# How to get data from object/string format to int in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, integer

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

[image: df]

I now want to get the column `Predictions` to an int value in order to plot the data. How could I do this?

Comment: df['Predictions'].str[0].astype(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just a list comprehension from pandas columns

you can use

```
df['Predictions'].str[0].astype(int)
```

to extract decimal values

```
df['Predictions'].str[0]-df['Predictions'].str[0].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a possibility to keep the comma values?

Comment: Glad to help, if you just want decimal values, you can use `df['Predictions'].str[0]-df['Predictions'].str[0].astype(int)`